# Significato di "pettinarsi i capelli a cercine"

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> Indossava un vestito di panno verde che sembrava broccato, con la giacca aderente alle spalle e il colletto nero di velluto, la gonna ampia, lunga fino alle caviglie, la sciarpa nera di seta, pendente al collo come una stola. **Si era pettinata i capelli a cercine** dietro la nuca; gli orecchi erano metà scoperti e decorati di due buccole nere contornate d’oro.

Alla voce ["cercine" del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cercine/) ho trovato:

> Acconciatura femminile del capo, con i capelli avviluppati a cercine.

Tuttavia, non riesco a capire del tutto bene in cosa consistono i capelli pettinati così. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Una immagine di Yulia Tymoshenko vale mille parole :-D

Comment: https://goo.gl/images/7qjVfd

Comment: Nel libro *Racconto d'autunno*, di Tommaso Landolfi, si parla anche di questo modo di pettinarsi e viene paragonato a un "cannuolo" (non so se questo significhi che a volte non c'è la treccia). Ecco la citazione: «La massa dei capelli bruni era pettinata in conseguenza, cioè in ampio **cercine o cannuolo** attorno alla fronte, in mezzo al quale spiccava un minuscolo diadema a forma di corona.»

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In breve

Sono capelli intrecciati *a cercine*, cioè in modo da ricordare o in modo da formare un cercine.
Il cercine era un panno avvolto a cerchio che veniva posto sulla testa per sostenere meglio i pesi.

Sono, in pratica, **capelli pettinati in trecce arrotolate a formare uno o più cerchi.**
Erano divenuti anche una moda già con Vibia Sabina, moglie dell'imperatore Adriano, che li portava sulla fronte, mentre la donna descritta nel brano citato li porta sulla nuca.

#### Qualche parola in più

Puoi provare a cercare qualche foto di statue antiche (vedi sotto).
Nel libro *"Ai confini di Roma: Tesori archeologici dai musei della provincia"* <sup>[[1](https://books.google.it/books?id=Im3iCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA79)]</sup>, pagina 79, c'è una foto ed anche una descrizione (statua proveniente da Locus Feronie).
Altri riferimenti, volendo, si possono trovare online in una pagina che parla di acconciature romane <sup>[[2](http://www.romanoimpero.com/2014/09/acconciature-romane.html)]</sup>.

Cercando ancora nell'universo Treccani oltre la pagina che hai già citato <sup>[[3](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cercine/)]</sup> per il significato di cercine (1.a.) e della relativa acconciatura (2.b.), penso sia utile anche la pagina di *"A (Preposizione)"* <sup>[[4](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/a-preposizione_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/)]</sup> dell'enciclopedia, 
dove si può trovare un cenno storico sull'uso di locuzioni avverbiali (in questo caso relative alla *moda*).

> Alcune locuzioni avverbiali costruite con la preposizione **a** (normali nell’uso odierno) sono state a lungo condannate dai puristi, perché rifatte su un modello francese (➔prestiti).
>   Tra queste, molte espressioni della moda
>   *alla Pompadour*, *alla Luigi XIV*

e nel nostro caso *"a cercine"*.

---

Da wikipedia (immagine e testo) <sup>[[5](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibia_Sabina)]</sup>

> Numerose sono le statue erette per celebrare Sabina, raffigurata con i capelli raccolti a treccia, rialzata in fronte con un nodo centrale ...

[image: Vibia Sabina Augusta, statua in Villa Adriana]

Comment: Grazie alla risposta, ma attento agli accenti, per piacere.

Comment: @DaG Non e' una questione di attenzione, e' che non li ho proprio sulla tastiera. E l'uso su internet e' di mettere apostrofi (il che potrebbe risolvere anche la questione se sulla u finale sia da mettere acuto o grave -Goidanich (http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accento-grave-e-acuto_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/) a meno che non si mutui dal LaTex l'uso di `\`` e `'` ...). Compatibilmente con le disponibilita' di tempo ci sarei tornato sopra, ma sei stato piu' veloce. Grazie. E' una domanda da meta il chiedere una estensione per le tastiere senza layout italiano?

Comment: “l'uso su internet e'...”, o almeno lo era prima che inventassero lo Unicode. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Cercando il significato di `cercine` sul dizionario <sup>[[1](http://www.dizionario.org/d/?pageurl=cercine)]</sup>  e altri riferimenti online: <sup>[[2](http://www.nicedie.it/home/index.php/cultura/item/1568-che-vuol-dire-conosci-significato-ed-etimologia-di-cercineitemSharingAnchor),[3](https://vestioevo.com/2015/06/19/cimiero-cercine-e-svolazzo/)]</sup>

ho trovato che deriva dal greco e significa `anello`, e si usa per descrivere una specie di ciambella di stoffa da mettere sul capo.

Mi immagino che in riferimento ai capelli indichi un'acconciatura a ciambella, forse una treccia a forma di cerchio.

Comment: Perché questo voto negativo?

Comment: Perché trovo che questa risposta non sia utile (che è la definizione di voto negativo): che cos'è un cercine in generale è già detto nella voce del Treccani a cui c'è un link nella domanda, e in mancanza di un dato certo l'ipotesi sulla treccia descritta nella risposta vale qualsiasi altra.

Comment: @Riccardo Sostanzialmente intuizione giusta anche se senza riferimenti definitivi...